# how to android touch in Unity?

Tags: unity

I am creating simple game for android.I used `touchphase.moved` to power up my ball and `touchphase.ended` to throw the ball.But what happened is the ball is thrown when I moved my finger in both x and y direction.But I want the ball to be thrown only while swiping in y direction.How to do that Suggest me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save the start position of the touch when the touchphase starts, you can compare the length between the start and the end position of the touch.

If you do that, you can then compare it to a specific range.

pseudo:

```
if(abs(touchStartPos.x - touchEndPos.x) < SpecifiedWidth)
{
    throw();
}
```

You can't expect the player to not move his finger a little bit to the left or right when he's throwing. Test!